# Is it possible to control atoms' motion? How to force-move an atom to other energy states?

Tags: atomic-physics

I've been wondering if it is possible to control atoms'/molecules' motion in a limited range of movement? (Take different orbits for example)

Let's think mathematically, is it possible to force a/an atom/molecule to only move between the desired A and B point(Or to force an atom to move to another orbital)?

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. For example, any atom inside a solid object is forced to be within a short distance of its lattice site. But I have a feeling this wasn't what you intended with your question.

Comment: In terms of signal processing, I was thinking if it is possible to limit atoms' motion while it CAN move to higher/lower energy states? For example, the atom has the capability to move around n =1 and n=7 and question is whether it's possible to keep atom between for example n=3 and n=5?

Comment: That also happens all the time, for example in fluorescent solids, which have been known about since at least 1938: https://www.nature.com/articles/1421081a0. An atom in a fluorescent solid absorbs a photon of a particular wavelength, transitions to a higher-energy state, then emits a different photon somewhat later, all without leaving its lattice site.

Comment: Thanks man! I got the answer, " the rate of excitation increases with the density and vice versa"

Comment: For a more serious answer, where we have a higher degree of control over the atom, see  magneto-optical traps, for example.